# Moving two different scrollviewers at the same time with two fingers

Tags: windows-phone, scrollviewer, gestures, simultaneous

I have two different scrollviewers and I want to be able to manipulate with both at the same time.
I draw the situation on the link beneath:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaOuC.png]

Somehow my phone can detect only one finger at a time. How do I change this?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819962/how-to-detect-two-simultaneous-touches . It might lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the XNA api's (i.e. what the game dev's use) to do this sort of thing.